# React-router unable to render on server side

Tags: react-router

I am trying to render a simple mock up on server side using react-router.

here is the code

```
import express from 'express'
import React from 'react'
import {Router} from 'react-router'
import routes from './routes'
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server'
var app = express()

app.use((req, res)=> {
    res.send('<!DOCTYPE html>' + ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<Router routes={routes}/>))
})

app.listen('8080', function () {
  console.log('Server started at port 8080')
})
```

and got the following error

`Invariant Violation: Hash history needs a DOM`

I am using the latest version of react-router. I got it working the older version

```
 import express from 'express'
import React from 'react'
import {Router} from 'react-router'
import routes from './routes'
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server'
var app = express()

app.use((req, res)=> {
  Router.run(routes, req.path, (Handler) => {
    res.send('<!DOCTYPE html>' + ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<Router routes={routes}/>))
  })
})

app.listen('8080', function () {
  console.log('Server started at port 8080')
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `match()` function and `<RoutingContext>` (`<RouterContext>` in the 2.x RCs) to render on the server. Please follow the server rendering guide: https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/v1.0.3/docs/guides/advanced/ServerRendering.md.